Movie with a lake, castle, books being burned and love affair between outsider and taken (maybe married) woman?
I remember watching it years ago, maybe a decade (although produced post-2000); on the other hand, my memories go as far to only grasp scenes and some subject matters of the film; so without further ado:

It's set in a recent time period, not further than the 19th century; I don't remember technologies or clothes to facilitate, my bad.
The protagonist, a male, not so old, but not quite young, travels to this place where there's a sort of lake and a castle.
In the castle lives this sort of important person of interest, a man, just a bit older than the protagonist, and the woman, far younger than this other male character; I don't remember what kind of relationship they had.
The protagonist establishes a relationship with that previously introduced woman from point 3; this same protagonist stays in their house (maybe, not 100% sure), keeping this relationship secret from the other man, also from point 3.
A scene in the night sees the protagonist go into the city where he sees an authority corp burning books, then he rushes to escape from those figures and between alleys and streets he encounters some sort of cult, (also can't remember if he is with anyone in that whole process).
At the end, the protagonist has to make a choice about leaving the lake, that place and everything in it, or stay and face consequences.

It's highly likely it's set in between the 1900's and 50's.
Response 1 .-Yeah, thanks. But I'm afraid It's all I have on time period. Clothing looks old, also can't be more specific. And, on to the actors or actresses, no clue, don't remember. Although, one thing I remember is that english language was the sound original version. – Henry M. 1 hour ago. 
Response 2.- And, not really, I mention it's set between those time periods; and based on certain other aspects, like, it's highly likely the people in the castle are aristocrats, also there's no light on the streets in the night sequence.

Welcome to Movies & TV!. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Also what time period..you mention the 16th century and the 1900's...it not clear when this movie is supposed to be set?

But you mentioned two periods. Which one was it?

Look, there's a huge difference between the 16th century and the 20th. Which was it set in?

You mention no further than the 16th century and between the 1900s and 1950s - I agree with @Paulie_D - which is it?

Ok, my bad, a typo. Corrected. The matter stands, the clothing seems to be around those times, I just can't place them totally, and more so, some movies do whatever they want about
clothing.
